# Skydrive does not sync on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, onedrive

I've been using Win 8.1 with Skydrive (not Pro) and keep experiencing problems with syncing.
**All this used to work fine in 7 and 8 using the old Skydrive client.**

If someone else uploads a .doc file to a shared folder, that file simply won't appear on my local Skydrive folder. I have to go out to the website and download it manually.

**Why is that?**

All my other files are there and available offline, but there are problems syncing when

a) a new file is added either via the webpage or via the Skydrive Windows client (it won't upload, or if it DOES upload it won't be there until hours or days later), and

b) a file is changed, moved or copied. Same thing.

My entire Skydrive folder size is around 3.1GB.

Comment: Windows 8.1 requires you to link your local account to your Microsoft Account in order to enable Skydrive syncing. There is no way currently around that requirement.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes of course I'm signed in with my Live account. It IS working, like I said above, just that it is not reliable.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, because most of your problems, seems to indicate your account wasn't linked or at least its the same behavior if that were the case.

Comment: Yes, thank you. What troubles me most is that I have no visual indication whatsoever about the sync status. No tray icon. Nothing. I have to guess. I don't ever know if the file is up to date or not. It is ridiculous and a major step back from Win7's Skydrive app.

Comment: I agree I miss the status icon also but the explorer integration is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows explorer, right click the skydrive folder `View Problems` to see why.

One thing that works for me every time is **right click the skydrive folder** (again) `Make available online-only`, then again right click the skydrive folder and `Make available offline`.

That forces the update.

Update: Onedrive (replacing skydrive) has some updates that may improve the sync process and (thank Microsoft) we got our old tray icon back.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 and I can't find the `View Problems` option.

Comment: John is talking about SkyDrive, safejrz is talking about Skype. Error message is in OneDrive App on the top right. But I think he has no error message there. Otherwise please explain where is "the Skype folder" and what is relying to OneDrive.

Comment: gee, I don't know why did I committed the same error 3 times in a row! thanks for pointing that out and I hope the edit helps with that miss understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Microsoft OneDrive Troubleshooter will help: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9835055